# Heroku Serving Files From Local File System

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I recently deployed an Heroku app written in Node.js, and so far everything is working fine.

However, I'm having a problem getting the deployed application to display pdf files that are generated by the app.

I have a page that allows people to dynamically generate a PDF file from some information they entered on a page.

The section looks like this:

[image: screen shot of where I generate the pdf]

The `Generate PDF` button submits a `POST` request that dynamically creates a view from the HTML on the page and uses the `HTML-PDF` module to turn it into a PDF file.

The code looks like this:

```
router.post('/formulas/:id/pdf', function(req, res){
var db = req.db.collection('users');
var id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
var pointer = {"formulas.$": 1, "_id": 0};
db.aggregate([
  {$match: {"formulas.f_id": id}},
  {$unwind: "$formulas"},
  {$match: {"formulas.f_id": id}},
  {$project : {"formulas": 1, "_id": 0}}
]).toArray(function(e, doc){
  if (e) {
    throw e;
} else {
  var html = null;
  ejs.renderFile('./views/pdf.ejs', {
    project: doc[0].formulas,
    title: 'Formula Info Report',
    description:  'PDF Report For Your Formula by Nutraceutical Pro',
    ID: 'pdf',
    keywords: 'PDF, PDF generator, Formula Info Report',
    user: req.user,
    loggedIn: req.isAuthenticated()
  }, function(err, results){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      }
      html = results;
    });
    var options = { format: 'Letter' };
    var path = './public/pdf/formula-' + req.params.id + '.pdf';
    pdf.create(html, options).toFile(path, function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (results) {
        res.end();
      }
    });
    }
  });
});
```

On my local machine this works fine.  However, when deployed to Heroku I get a `Cannot GET` error, because it's trying to get the file from my local server.

This is an example URL that generates when the `POST` request is submitted:

[image: URL generated from POST request]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Using that address from the browser, you are making a GET request (and not a POST request) to the server. Did you set up a GET request on server-side with that address that allows the download of the generated file? 
To do this you should use the download function of the response ([Express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)) by passing the URL of the file.

Comment: So would the answer be as simple as changing the `POST` request to a `GET` request?  Why is it trying to `GET` the file from my local file system and not the corresponding place on the Heroku server?

Comment: On Heroku app, when you click on "Generate PDF" button, are you redirect to localhost? The "Generate PDF" must only create the PDF file or also download it? If so, try to change `res.end();` with `res.download(<file_url>)`